# Unselect single option dropdown python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am having an issue unselecting a selected option after selecting it using webdriver. I keep getting error raise NotImplementedError("You may only deselect options of a multi-select")
NotImplementedError: You may only deselect options of a multi-select

How can a selected pull down menu item be unselected? My code is below.

HTML code:

```
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="Item 2 (1)">Item 2</option>
<option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
```

Python Webdriver:

```
options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") 
for x in range(1,len(options)): 
    option = options[x]  
    options_list.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
    item_selection = Select(select)
    item_selection.select_by_visible_text("Item 1")
time.sleep()
item_selection.deselect_by_visible_text("Item 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.select_by_index(0)` or possibly `.select_by_value("")`. The first one should work... I'm not sure about the second.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dropdown select class does not have multi-select which  means that you can only select a item from the dropdown list at a time and for all deselect functions there is a check that if

```
if not self.is_multiple:
            raise NotImplementedError("You may only deselect options of a multi-select")
```

and because of which its giving you error which is expected since deselect should only work with multi-select dropdowns.

The work around is use select_by_index() or select_by_value() or select_by_visible_text() of another element to change the selection from the selected one to another.

And if you are practising deselect then try it on page which supports multi-select